# Create a stream with fixed length based on a longer stream

Tags: c#, serialization, stream

Many deserializing APIs take streams, and will read to the end of the stream and error out if they run past the end of the serialized object before reaching the end of the stream.
In my stream, I serialize several objects in sequence. Then I want to deserialize them from that stream later. I know the length of each object and could tell them how far to read the stream if they took such a parameter, but they don't.

I think I could fix this by creating a "sub-stream" that takes the longer stream as a first argument to its constructor along with a length, after which the sub-stream would claim to be at an end, which would cause the deserializer to terminate and the parent stream would be positioned correctly to start deserializing the next object.

So my question is, is there already a class in the BCL to support this, or does anyone have an example of such a custom stream?

Hint: I *am* talking about streams here deliberately, not memory buffers. I know I can read out x bytes from a stream and then base a `MemoryStream` on that, but I can't assume that the entire stream will fit in memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such class in BCL.

It is pretty straightforward code to write if you just need synchronous read operations - derive from `Stream` and implement `Read` that redirects to internal stream with correct bounds checks. You may need to implement `CanSeek`/`Length` properties and `ReadByte` if it is used in your code.